# Is D3D11_BLEND_DESC's IndependentBlendEnable safe to use in D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0?

Tags: directx

I'm developing a deferred renderer with the DirectX 11 API and need to vary the blend state across the render targets.  DX10.0 only allowed one set of blend ops:

```
typedef struct D3D10_BLEND_DESC {
  BOOL           AlphaToCoverageEnable;
  BOOL           BlendEnable[8];
  D3D10_BLEND    SrcBlend;
  D3D10_BLEND    DestBlend;
  D3D10_BLEND_OP BlendOp;
  D3D10_BLEND    SrcBlendAlpha;
  D3D10_BLEND    DestBlendAlpha;
  D3D10_BLEND_OP BlendOpAlpha;
  UINT8          RenderTargetWriteMask[8];
} D3D10_BLEND_DESC;
```

whereas the DX11 API has the flexibility to specify 8.

```
typedef struct D3D11_BLEND_DESC {
  BOOL                           AlphaToCoverageEnable;
  BOOL                           IndependentBlendEnable;
  D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC RenderTarget[8];
} D3D11_BLEND_DESC;

typedef struct D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC {
  BOOL           BlendEnable;
  D3D11_BLEND    SrcBlend;
  D3D11_BLEND    DestBlend;
  D3D11_BLEND_OP BlendOp;
  D3D11_BLEND    SrcBlendAlpha;
  D3D11_BLEND    DestBlendAlpha;
  D3D11_BLEND_OP BlendOpAlpha;
  UINT8          RenderTargetWriteMask;
} D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC;
```

Now using my DX11 card at D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0, I don't get errors or warnings creating and setting state that has IndependentBlendEnable true.  Is it safe to trust this outcome as representative of what would happen on DX10.0 hardware, or is feature level checking only an approximate guide?

Answer (score 1):

It will fail on DX10.0 hardware.  As my test had no variety in the RenderTarget[] array, it seems DX detected that the value of IndependentBlendEnable made no difference and ignored it.  It would have been helpful to have been given a warning, but none was output, leading me to suspect that independent blending was being solved in software rather than hardware.  Anyway, when varying RenderTarget[] data, the error below pops up and everything makes sense again, albeit inconveniently in this case.

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateBlendState: SrcBlend[ 4 ] does not equal SrcBlend[ 0 ]
and D3D10.1 hardware is not supported. When GetFeatureLevel returns
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0 or less, any enabled render target blending must use the same
blending configuration. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #212: CREATEBLENDSTATE_INVALIDSRCBLEND]
```